# How do I post a file to Server using Deno fetch API / or convert a file to a RedableStream?

Tags: deno

How do I convert a file to Readable stream ?
I am trying to use deno's fetch api to do this, which requires a readable stream as body to put something on server.
I am not able to figure out how to convert a file to ReadableStream ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way yet to convert a `Reader` to a `ReadableStream`.

You can convert it using the following code:

```js
const file = await Deno.open("./some-file.txt", { read: true });

const stream = new ReadableStream({
  async pull(controller) {
    try {
      const b = new Uint8Array(1024 * 32);
      const result = await file.read(b);
      if (result === null) {
        controller.close();
        return file.close();
      }

      controller.enqueue(b.subarray(0, result));
    } catch (e) {
      controller.error(e);
      controller.close();
      file.close();
    }
  },
  cancel() {
    // When reader.cancel() is called
    file.close();
  },
});

// ReadableStream implements asyncIterator
for await (const chunk of stream) {
  console.log(chunk);
}
```

Have in mind that Deno (1.0.5) `fetch` does not yet support a `ReadableStream` as request body.

So currently to post a file, you'll need to buffer the contents.

```js
const body = await Deno.readAll(file);
await fetch('http://example.com', { method: 'POST', body });
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this with the file as a form data parameter instead of the entire body?